Complexity of algorithm waiting $e^{n}$ seconds
A dumb question in complexity theory.
Let's consider an algorithm that solves the following problem:
is $e^{n}$ time passed?
f(n):
   1. let t = get_current_time()
   2. wait(e^n)
   3. return get_current_time()-t

Naively, I'd say this algorithm takes exponential time given instruction 2, thus placing it outside the P class. However, it's easy to verify its answer is correct by computing $e^{n}$, thus placing it inside NP.
What am I missing?

The classes P and NP are not sets of algorithms, they are sets of decision problems. So it makes no sense to say that the algorithm is in/outside of P or NP.

There are some problems in your question:

What is the computation model, and what is the operation "wait" in your model?
"Is $e^n$ time passed?" is a very unclear statement. What is the input, and what is the question asked?
"this algorithm takes exponential time given instruction 2, thus placing it outside the P class" suggests that you are forced to execute the algorithm to get an answer.

